# logstash-input-mongodb errors on logstash 5.1.2

Tags: ruby, logstash

I'm trying to run the plugin on logstash 5.1.2, and getting the error: 
**Direct event field references (i.e. event['field'] = 'value') have been disabled in favor of using event get and set methods (e.g. event.set('field', 'value')). Please consult the Logstash 5.0 breaking changes documentation for more details.**

> 19:20:09.456 [LogStash::Runner] INFO  logstash.inputs.mongodb - Using
>   version 0.1.x input plugin 'mongodb'. This plugin isn't well supported
>   by the community and likely has no maintainer.
>
> D,
>   [2017-02-09T19:20:09.766000 #7068] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding
>   localhost:27017 to the cluster. | runtime: 0.0000ms
>
> D,
>   [2017-02-09T19:20:12.839000 #7068] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND |
>   namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0
>   project=nil | runtime: 3066.0000ms 19:20:12.845
>   [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.inputs.mongodb - Registering
>   MongoDB input
>
> D, [2017-02-09T19:20:12.936000 #7068] DEBUG -- : MONGODB
>   | COMMAND | namespace=test.$cmd selector={:listCollections=>1,
>   :cursor=>{}, :filter=>{:name=>{"$not"=>/system.|\$/}}}
>   flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 22.0001ms
>   19:20:13.140 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline -
>   Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4,
>   "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5,
>   "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500} 19:20:13.151 [[main]-pipeline-manager]
>   INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
>
> D,
>   [2017-02-09T19:20:13.356000 #7068] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | QUERY |
>   namespace=test.auditcommunications
>   selector={:_id=>{:$gt=>BSON::ObjectId('0761b057fccc5c277c23dfbe')}}
>   flags=[:slave_ok] limit=50 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 224.9999ms
>   19:20:13.420 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully
>   started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600} 19:20:13.647
>   [[main]
>
> Plugin:
>   "mongodb://localhost:27017/test",
>   placeholder_db_dir=>"/elk/logstash-mongodb/",
>   placeholder_db_name=>"logstash_sqlite.db",
>   collection=>"auditcommunications", batch_size=>50,
>   id=>"797b2fd78162084f6d57991a196d656a6c95f190-1", enable_metric=>true,
>   codec=>"plain_cd856514-8fcc-43ad-becd-9497e98577b9", enable_metric=>true,
>   charset=>"UTF-8">, since_table=>"logstash_since",
>   parse_method=>"flatten", isodate=>false, retry_delay=>3,
>   generateId=>false, unpack_mongo_id=>false, message=>"Default
>   message...", interval=>1>
>
> Error: Direct event field references
>   (i.e. event['field'] = 'value') have been disabled in favor of using
>   event get and set methods (e.g. event.set('field', 'value')). Please
>   consult the Logstash 5.0 breaking changes documentation for more
>   details.
>
> D, [2017-02-09T19:20:14.782000 #7068] DEBUG -- : MONGODB |
>   QUERY | namespace=test.auditcommunications
>   selector={:_id=>{:$gt=>BSON::ObjectId('0761b057fccc5c277c23dfbe')}}
>   flags=[:slave_ok] limit=50 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 128.9999ms

(sorry about the formatting)

My configuration is pretty much copy pasted from the instructions:

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
    placeholder_db_dir => '/elk/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'auditcommunications'
    batch_size => 50
  }
}

filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
  }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using version 0.1.x of `logstash-input-mongodb`, which is an old version. You should use the latest 0.4.0 version which is compatible with Logstash 5 thanks to [PR #53](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/pull/53).

You can try to update your plugin with:

```
bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-input-mongodb
```

When done, run the following command and make sure that `logstash-input-mongodb` 0.4.0 is installed.

```
bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose
```

Then your plugin will work again.

Comment: So I did notice and was suspicious of the "Using version 0.1.x input plugin" in the logs, but I had already checked the library version and saw that it was 0.3.0 not 0.1.0, so I thought it was an issue with the library. I just missed that the latest version is 0.4.0 and not 0.3.0. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a moment could you also check out my other question: https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/issues/56  - or should I ask a separate question?